# Three js - basic shader for postprocessing

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, glsl, webgl

I have been trying to write a simple shader for adding noise. But I can't get the uv coordinates with the following settings.

Fragment Shader:

```
uniform float seed;
uniform sampler2D pass;

varying vec2 vUv;

void main (){
    //noise
    vec2 pos = gl_FragCoord.xy;
    pos.x *= seed;
    pos.y *= seed;
    float lum=fract(sin(dot(pos ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 434658.5453116487577816842168767168087910388737310);

    vec4 tx = texture2D(pass, vUv);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(tx.r*lum,tx.g*lum,tx.b*lum,1.0);

}
```

Vertex  Shader:

```
varying vec2 vUv;

void main (){
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
}
```

Rendering:

```
OBJECT.material = OBJECT.mat.flat; // THREE MeshPhongMaterial ({color: 0xE40D59,shading:THREE.FlatShading});

RENDERER.render(SCENE,CAMERA,BEAUTY_PASS,false);

OBJECT.material = OBJECT.mat.noise; // THREE ShaderMaterial

RENDERER.render(SCENE,CAMERA);
```

I get the following error:

> Error: WebGL: DrawElements: bound vertex attribute buffers do not have
>   sufficient size for given indices from the bound element array @
>   http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js:439

I did some tests and I can run it by picking the same coordinate for all the pixel

```
vec4 tx = texture2D(pass, vec2(0.5,0.5));
```

which display my object with a reddish noisy color, however the vUv variable works perfectly fine if I remove the first rendering pass (`RENDERER.render(SCENE,CAMERA,BEAUTY_PASS,False)`).

Why I can't get the uv coordinate on the second render? According to several examples I should be able to render it using the same scene and camera like in this [example](http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/postprocessing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an initial texture, the geometry will not have the necessary baked-in WebGL UV buffers.

There are several solutions, but perhaps the easiest is to be sure that the first rendering of the mesh has a texture. A simple white one will do.

three.js r.58

Comment: Thanks! Using a white texture in the first render,it actually solves the problem and keeps the uv coordinates. However now my icosahedron is a potato. Do you think this is due to the original uv mapping?

Comment: It's likely your lighting model, and unrelated to this question. Can you make a new post for the new issue